# ListView directly goes to the last item

Tags: android, listview

`ListView` directly goes to the last item after adding the new list which is coming from the web service. It is not maintaining its position. Everything is working fine but my list is taking me to the last item. 
    By using `setSelection` and `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop`, I have achieved this but it is showing scrolling animation. I don't want that to happen. I have tried below code till now:

Note: My listview only contains textview.

```
  listview.setSelection(position);

listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(mylastPosition,0,0);
```

And this

Below code work perfectly if list is added programatically(hardcore) instead of getting the list from webservice.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int firstVisibleItem, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+firstVisibleItem>= totalCount)
            {
               //code for getting new list 
               loadNewDataFromWS();
           }
    });
```

is it happening because I am adding the list in another thread instead of main thread?

Comment: are you trying to do lazy loading?

Comment: I am getting new list from asyncTask

Comment: Do you want to load more items (next page?) when scrolling to the bottom?

Comment: yes. i want to load next page when i reach to last item while scrolling.

Comment: then your approach is incorrect. Search for `lazy loading android listview`, and you will find a lot of correct examples

Comment: ok. i will search. thanx for suggestion. :)

Comment: i am not getting it. if i am adding list dynamically in program then above code is working properly, but when i add the list in asyncTask it is giving me the problem

Comment: that depends on which method of asynctask are you adding items

Comment: i am adding items in onPostExcecute method after receiving the response.

Comment: i got the solution. thnx for the suggestion though. i set transcriptMode  property of listview to disabled by doing this android:transcriptMode = "disabled" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution while watching video on listview.
and the solution is by just setting the `transcriptMode` property of the listview to `disabled`.

```
android:transcriptMode = "disabled" - does not scroll
android:transcriptMode = "normal" - scrolls to the bottom if last item is visible
android:transcriptMode = "disabled" - always scrolls to the bottom
```